# bash script for TCAdmin

Tags: bash

Im having a issue with this script that I made, im just learning and I have no errors, but it is not working

Basicly I want to read all bsp files on the maps folder and then write all the names in one file nammed maplist.txt but remove all the bsp extension from the name, I will give an example: I have only this 2 maps in my maps folder

```
de_dust2.bsp
de_cache.bsp
```

After running the script it will generates a file named maplist.txt and replace that file for the one that is already there in the past csgo/ with this lines:

```
de_dust2
de_cache
```

My code is:

```
find csgo/maps/ -name "*.bsp" -exec basename {} .bsp \; |
sort | uniq > maplist.txt
```

This works:

```
find csgo/maps/ -name "*.bsp" -printf '%P\n' |
sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | sort -u > csgo/maplist.txt |
find csgo/maps/ -name "*.bsp" -printf '%P\n' echo "\n\n\n\n+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n|                     Your maplist.txt has been updated!                            \n|        YOUR OLD MAPLIST HAVE BEEN UPDATED PLEASE CHECK IT OUT!!!                  |\n+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+|" |
sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'
```

But `echo` is not working

Get this error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: echo
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Comment: you may replace `sort | uniq` by `sort -u` (not an answer, just a remark)

Comment: How is your script not working?

Comment: `find` has `-printf` formatting codes which can probably be used to avoid the call to `basename` entirely.

Comment: @tripleee it is not making his function, not generating the maplist.

Comment: @tripleee edited now

Comment: @Amessihel I made it working, could you see why echo not working ?

Comment: I suggest you to try: `find csgo/maps/ -name "*.bsp" -exec basename {} .bsp \; | sort | uniq | tee maplist.txt`. If you see something displayed, maplist.txt should be updated.

Comment: @Amessihel just want to put echo working to give a message that I want after list all maps

Comment: So the error is not in the code you posted, but in the missing newline before the `echo` which is the next command after the one you asked about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you hope for the second `find` to accomplish over the first or what piping the output from the first `find` into it is supposed to accomplish.  (Because of the redirection to a file, the pipe is empty anyway.)  But reading between the lines and guessing a bit, I imagine you are looking for something like

```
find csgo/maps/ -name "*.bsp" -printf '%f\n' |
sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | sort -u > csgo/maplist.txt
cat <<\____HERE
     Really loud annoying message here.
____HERE
```